# Why do I get undefined when mapping and passing through a prop (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can get the data out correctly and see it in the console as I want it to display but mapping and getting it through is the issue I seem to fail on..

[image: Image here]

##### This is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import server from '../backend/server.jsx';
import Home from './Home';

function ListImage() {

    const [api, setApi]  = useState('');
    const getAllData = () => {
        axios
          .get(`${server}/images`)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setApi(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      getAllData();
    },[]);

    return (
        <>
                {api ? 
                api.map((item) => {
                    console.log(item);
                    return <Home data={item.data} />;
                    
                }): <p>Not found</p>}
        </>
    )
}

export default ListImage
```

##### And then passing to this where i only get undefined in console

```
import React from 'react'


function Home({ data }) {
console.log(data)
  
  return (
    <>
  <p>{data}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a ```data``` property on the ```item```?

Comment: What does `response` and `response.data` look like ?

Comment: What is the console.log of item? 
Does it have a data property?

Comment: Posted the question too early, item didin't have data property. Brain going slow-mo... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. I think your map function gets called when the initial render. Make sure the response. data should return an array.

ps: You render your home component in an array. That's wrong. Pass the data to the component and map your array on the home component.

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';
    import server from '../backend/server.jsx';
    import Home from './Home';
    
    function ListImage() {
    
        const [data, setData]  = useState(null);
        const getAllData = () => {
            axios
              .get(`${server}/images`)
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setData(response.data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
        useEffect(() => {
          getAllData();
        },[]);
    
        return (
            <>
                    {api ? <Home data={data} /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default ListImage
```